# Easiest way to collect funds of big lists of bitcoin privatekeys

Tags: private-key, ecommerce, import

I am setting up an webstore where you can pay with bitcoins. Therefore I created a bulk list on bitcoinaddress.org. I save the public addresses in a database and attach one to each transaction. Then I wait to recieve a notification from bitcoinmonitor.net and complete the transaction.

That will work fine I think, but how can I get the funds from all the different addresses? I know you can import in some software a private key, but it is too much work to do for each order. Do you know something easier to collect the funds of all the generated addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would import all the private keys into my wallet immediately after generating them with bitaddress.org.  There's no need to wait for them to be used.

See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4355/659) for how to import the whole collection at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use your own wallet (and local bitcoind) but instead want to use a hosted solution, you can import all the private keys into Mt. Gox (redeem private key).

Mt. Gox will then sweep any incoming transactions into your Mt. Gox account.  They even have an API for adding [(redeeming) these private keys](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#redeem_a_private_key).

Comment: The API looks very useful, but I prefer to use my own wallet. Thank you anyway.